# Why is the actual behavior of my C++ program different from what is described in the C++ Primer,Chinese version

Tags: c++

This is my code.

```
template<typename T>
void func(T&& t){
    cout << "T&&" << endl;
}
template<typename T>
void func(const T& t){
    cout << "const T&" << endl;
}
int main() {
    const string s1 = "b";
    func(std::move(s1));
    return 0;
}
```

This is the result of the code.

> T&&

I passed a const rvalue to the function func, and it used the first version.But according to the book's description, the second version should be used.C++ Primer says:

> ```
> // Template function binding to non-const rvalue
> template <typename T> void f(T&&);
> // Template function binding to lvalue and const rvalue
> template <typename T> void f(const T&)
> ```
>
> Just like non-template functions, the first version binds to modifiable rvalues,while the second version binds to lvalues or const rvalues.

I want to know whether there is an issue with the book's description or if there is some other reason for this.

Comment: For more info about posting text as images, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/389289

Comment: `// Template function binding to non-const rvalue
template <typename T> void f(T&&);` This is wrong. This is a function with a forwarding reference. The book might be translated incorrectly. I suggest that you use the English book.

Comment: I found it on the page 689 of the English book. It's the error, the information is not true. As I said it's a forwarding reference, not a binding to non const rvalue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`T` is deduced as `const string`, then `void func<const string>(const string&&)` is a perfect match.

`string &&` would not be viable with the `const string&&` returned from `std::move`, but the author made a mistake in assuming `T&&` would be `string &&`.